# How do I say that a program (coding) "Works!"

Tags: translation, vocabulary

I'm trying to say a program (as in something a programmer/程序员） finally works! 
Is there a way to translate this "works" into chinese?

Could I say 
我的代码终于可以了！？ Or is there a way that is more clear what I mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`我的代码终于可以了` is close to `My code is ok now`, you can say something more clearly like `我的代码终于可以`

```
运行
工作
跑（起来）
```

`了！`

Comment: Is there a difference between 运行 and 跑？ Would you say that 运行 is too formal to use in a speaking context?

Comment: @Stephen `跑` is used in spoken language usually, but not in written language, while `运行` can be used for both.

Answer (score 2):

“运行”

“通过”

我的代码终于可以运行了！
it's usual way to say so

Answer (score 2):

We say 跑起来了(informal).

这破程序我改了半天,终于能跑起来了！
[I worked and worked and worked on that 'piece of code', finally it worked.]

Comment: Could I simply say "终于跑了！“？

Comment: Nope. 跑了 might refer to ESCAPED. 跑起来了means RUNNING/WORKING.

Comment: But you can use it in a question like 这软件能在我机器上跑吗？ or 我电脑的配置跑不动/带不起这游戏

Answer (score 2):

终于跑了！should be a good one. (Literally means finally - it is - running) In this case, 跑 means a program IS RUNNING, but not ESCAPING.

Answer (score 1):

Like people already suggested, its good to say:

> 我的代码终于跑起来了！

“跑” as in the sense of "to run" (the program) is a calque from English to Chinese. It's very literal and very easy to understand. Just like "sky craping tower" is loaned and translated literally as “摩天楼” （rub－sky－building）and very much make sense.

Comment: sky craping tower?